# Insert into Table & extract last ID

Tags: php, mysql

Afternoon geniuses, Hoping you can help.
This was inserting into the tables  Twitch & Birds before i added upload image to it, Now the only part that works is the image upload. this is very simple code but cant work out why it's not adding.

Also how can i get the auto increment ID from The TWITCH table once it works.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('dbconnect.php');

//Set Variables from Form
$species =($_POST['Species']);
$age =($_POST['Age']);
$sex =($_POST['Sex']);
$location =($_POST['Location']);
$date_seen = date("Y-m-d");
$time_seen =($_POST['Time']);
$twitch =($_POST['Comments']);
//$twitch_id=(". mysql_insert_id()");

 //Insert Into Birds table
 $query1 = "INSERT INTO Birds (Species, Age, Sex, Location, Date_Seen, Time_Seen,     Comments) VALUES
  ( '$species', '$age', '$sex', '$location', '$date_seen', '$time_seen', '$twitch')";
 result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

 //Insert into Twitch table
  query2 = "INSERT INTO Twitch (Twitch_ID, Twitch) VALUES( 'NULL', '$twitch')";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

 // Validate and upload image file
 if ( !preg_match( '/gif|png|x-png|jpeg/', $_FILES['userFile']['type']) ) {
  die('<p>Only browser compatible images allowed</p></body></html>');
 } else if ( strlen($_POST['altText']) < 9 ) {
  die('<p>Please provide meaningful alternate text</p></body></html>');
 } else if ( $_FILES['userFile']['size'] > 1116384 ) {
 die('<p>Sorry file too large</p></body></html>');

 // Connect to database
 } else if ( !($conn=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)) ) {
  die('<p>Error connecting to database</p></body></html>');
 } else if ( !(mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)) ) {
  die('<p>Error selecting database</p></body></html>');

 // Copy image file into a variable
 } else if ( !($handle = fopen ($_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], "r")) ) {
   die('<p>Error opening temp file</p></body></html>');
 } else if ( !($image = fread ($handle, filesize($_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name']))) ) {
  die('<p>Error reading temp file</p></body></html>');
} else {
  fclose ($handle);

 // Commit image to the database
   $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $image);
   $alt = htmlentities($_POST['altText']);
   $query3 = 'INSERT INTO Image (Image_Name, Image_Type, Description, Image) VALUES ("' . $_FILES['userFile']['type'] . '","' . $_FILES['userFile']['name']  . '","' . $alt  .    '","' . $image . '")';
  if ( !(mysqli_query($conn, $query3)) ) {
     die('<p>Error writing image to database</p></body></html>');
    } else {
    header ("Location: TwitchWall.php");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id()` returns last inserted autoincrement ID.

Comment: SQL injection open in the code. Here is some reading :) 

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php
http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @RonniSkansing: he is using mysqli...

Comment: query2 = "INSERT INTO Twitch (Twitch_ID, Twitch) VALUES( 'NULL', '$twitch')";. you forgot to add a $ sign. is it working in page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`mysqli_insert_id`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id).

> The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

**Object oriented style**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ...";
$con->query($query);
echo $con->insert_id;
```

**Procedural style**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ...";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 'mysqli', try:

```
$last_id = mysqli::$insert_id;
```

Otherwise, with 'mysql', use:

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Although, the older 'mysql' method is **deprecated**.
See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_insert_id() to get inserted recorded ID. But mysql_* all function are deprecated so use mysqli_insert_id() or PDO::lastInsertId().

Answer (score 0):

To get the last auto-inserted ID you can use

```
mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Comment: Thanks for mysqli_insert_id().. Can anyone see why the top two queries aren't insert into the tables.